# How to accept rules or conditions from user and automatically apply on pandas dataframe(cataloging rules)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have a pandas dataframe lets take example it is diamonds data .
I want to accept rules from user and appy it on pandas dataframe using fastapi,python,pandas.
User can give any type of rule.

```
def rules(get_target_dir : utils.target_directory):
    global df
    col1 = get_target_dir.column1
    col2 = get_target_dir.column2
    target_directory = get_target_dir.target_directory
    df = utils.df
    corr = utils.df[col1].corr(df[col2])
    if corr > 0.90:
        print("highly correlated")
    else:
        print("not correlated")
```

Here iam giving the condition or rule rather I want to accept from user and apply it on pandas dataframe.

Comment: What you're thinking of is called Excel.

Comment: It's difficult to accept "any" rule unless you use some very unsafe method like `eval` and even then the user would need to give a correct code as input.

Comment: If user wants to check null and outliers in columns and we want to accept that rule or conditions from user and apply it on dataframe and then show the result

Comment: user can give any rule or any condition I want to accept it and apply it on dataframe can you please tell me how should i go for this approach

Comment: It's extremely vague. You need to define what you mean by "accept any condition".

Comment: I agree with the previous commenters about the "any condition" issue. My suggestion will be to come up with a list of possible conditions the user might be interested in and develop a corresponding syntax for how the user can specify call that condition.